# Pass the parameter in Vaadin 14 between two routes

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14

Help me, please, to make navigating between views in vaadin application.
In OrdersView class I create a link like

```
UI.getCurrent().navigate(FullOrderView.class, new RouteParameters("orderId", "123"));
```

In FullOrderView class I specify a route like this

```
@Route("order/:orderId")
public class FullOrderView extends AppLayout implements HasUrlParameter<String>{
    @Override
    public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event, String parameter) {
    }
```

but I get an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation target 'com.example.crudwithvaadin.FullOrderView' requires a parameter.
```

If I remove a "implements HasUrlParameter" and setParameter() I get an error

```
No route found for the given navigation target 'com.example.crudwithvaadin.FullOrderView' and parameters '{}'
```

How do I fix the error and pass the parameter correctly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are combining different Router features. The usage of Route template parameter (:orderId) has to be used in conjunction with `BeforeEnterObserver` instead of `HasUrlParamter`.

Comment: Thanks, but when I write 
`@Route("order/:orderId") 
public class FullOrderView extends AppLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver { 
  private Optional<String> orderId; 

  @Override public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) { 
    orderId = event.getRouteParameters().get("orderId"); 
} `

I get an error 
` No route found for the given navigation target 'com.example.crudwithvaadin.FullOrderView' and parameters '{}' ` 

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The orderId is required, opening without it, isn't possible. If this is an optional param :orderId? has to be used.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me. I implemented routing using the HasUrlParameter(). This is the only option that works for me. 
`@Route("order")
public class FullOrderView extends AppLayout implements HasUrlParameter<String> {
  @Override
  public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event, @OptionalParameter String parameter) {`